# Steam Change Date Format

Tags: steam, pc

In Steam, is there a way to change the date format displayed? An example is a coupon, it says it runs out on `10/12/2014`

I see the 10th of December 2014, but it's actually the 12th of October 2014.

Is there a way to change this? I saw on a forum that it adjusts to your computer's format. I'm on a Mac and my date format is `dd:mm:yyyy` but Steam is still set to `mm:dd:yyyy`

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, there is not.

Some kind of explanation:
This topic comes up in the steam community from time to time, but the developers really doesn't seem to take any notice of it.
I seems like steam treats american English (and it's timeformat) as the standard, and therefore does not want to change the way their date formatting is set up.

Some report that steam should adjust to the way your computers calender is set up. But as far as I can see, it seems like the ones that are saying this, are people from the states (and their computers calender is therefor the same as steams).